# How to Disable Social Tagging for particular Column?

Tags: 2010, tagging, social-tag

I have a document library and there are 10 custom Columns out of which 3 are Managed Metadata Columns.

1) Department

2) Permissions

3) Category

From the above Columns I have to display "**Category**" in Tag Cloud Web Part but if I checked "**Save metadata on this list as social tags**"  from Library Settings, Managed Metadata from all 3 columns are showing in Tag Cloud and if I don't Checked on this column then Tags are not showing.

What Should I do to display tags only from Category Column?

NOTE : I have to use Custom Column other than Enterprise Keywords Column.